# Eval() versus Function() for evaluating string expressions in JavaScript: Not the same behavior

Tags: javascript, function, security, scripting, eval

I have the following string expression:

```
string_expression = "var sum = 0;\nfor (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {\n    var index = i + 1;\n    sum += (index / ((index * Math.sqrt(index + 1)) + ((index + 1) * Math.sqrt(index))))\n}\nalert(sum)
```

If I use eval() it works fine:

```
eval(string_expression)
```

But if I use Function, like this:

```
Function("return " + string_expression)();
```

....I get the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'`

Why would this behave differently? I am looking for an alternative to `eval()` for security reasons, and thought the `Function` approach would work the same with string expressions. Is there a better alternative to `eval()` that works the same in terms of being able to parse string expressions?

Comment: When you concatenate `"return"` to `string_expression` it becomes `"return var sum = 0;"...`, which is not valid JS.

Comment: At the end of `string_expression`, change `alert(sum)` to `return sum` and don't concatenate anything to the beginning of `string_expression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're feeding different things into them. `return var sum = 0` is a syntax error. For similar behavior, leave out the `return`. Your string expression `alert`s rather than returning a value:

```js
var string_expression = "var sum = 0;\nfor (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {\n    var index = i + 1;\n    sum += (index / ((index * Math.sqrt(index + 1)) + ((index + 1) * Math.sqrt(index))))\n}\nalert(sum)";

Function(string_expression)()
```

If you want it to *return* the value, you'll have to modify the string; here I've changed `alert(sum)` to `return sum`:

```js
var string_expression = "var sum = 0;\nfor (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {\n    var index = i + 1;\n    sum += (index / ((index * Math.sqrt(index + 1)) + ((index + 1) * Math.sqrt(index))))\n}\nreturn sum;";

const sum = Function(string_expression)();
alert(sum);
```